# How to post an object with an excel file to api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I want to send an object which is almost big along with an excel file to api, but only my photo is recognized and my object is not sent, and I get the [object Object] error. I know that this error is for the completion of a string Yes, but I don't know what to do, I will leave people in the future

```
 const formData: any = new FormData();
 onSubmit={(values) => {
    formData.append("file", fileList || "");

    let info: any = {
      id: values.id,
      brandId: values.brandId,
      brandName: values.brandName,
      campaignDurationDTO: values.campaignDurationDTO,
      favoriteStructures: values.favoriteStructures,
      status: "not_active",
      geographicalInfoDTO: values.geographicalInfoDTO,
      campaignCode: values.campaignCode,
      phase: values.phase,
      reportScheduleType: values.reportScheduleType,
    };
    let ali = JSON.stringify(info);

    formData.append("properties", JSON.stringify(info));
    props.onSubmit?.("planos", formData, true);
  }}
```

[image]

This is the output

what should i do?
thanks

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of code, post the code directly and format it as code.

Comment: Can you tell us what is the value of `info` right before you append it to the formData?

Answer (score 0):

Try using `JSON.stringify(info)`

You may have to parse it back into JSON on the receiving end

Comment: I did this and all the keys were converted to string and finally I parsed it, but it still gives the same error [object Object], is it generally possible to send a json along with an excel file?    
There is no other solution?

Comment: It probably depends on whether the API endpoint is able to accept JSON payloads. Presumably you are creating a new formData object somewhere?
const formData = new FormData();